# Why is the div in a flexbox second row floating to the right

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a 3 column flexbox layout, with this css code:

```
.block  {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.itemPads {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid #009900;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

and this html:

```
<div class="block" >
     <div class="itemPads">
        <p>Column 1</p>
     </div> 
     <div class="itemPads">
        <p>Column 2</p>
     </div> 
     <div class="itemPads">
        <p>Column 3</p>
     </div> 
     <div class="itemPads">
        <p>Column 4</p>
     </div> 
     <div class="itemPads">
        <p>Column 5</p>
     </div> 

</div>
```

I don't understand why block 5 floats to the right, like this:

[image: Layout]

How do I get the 5th block to be in the center?

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Because of `justify-content: space-between`, try `justify-content: flex-start`.

Comment: thanks - that fixes the position, now just need to sort the spacing....

Comment: That is because of the `width`, you probably don't need it. Try removing the `width` and then use margins if you need gaps.